# How to add a dropbox upload button to a retool app

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, retool

Hi I am trying to create a dropbox upload button in custom component in retool. This is the code I am using however it only lets me select a file but does not upload it or interact with dropbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="MY_APP_KEY"></script>

<script>
  function uploadFile(files) {
    var file = files[0]; // Get the first file from the selected files

    var accessToken = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'; // Replace with your access token

    var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: accessToken });
    dbx.filesUpload({ path: '/' + file.name, contents: file })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully!', response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file.', error);
      });
  }
</script>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="uploadFile(this.files)" />
```

I have entered my access token and app key correctly so I am not sure what the problem is, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What error/output do you get? Looking at your code though, I see you're loading the dropins.js script, which is meant for pre-built components like [the Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser), but then you're attempting to use [the Dropbox JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) (not a pre-built component). To use the SDK methods, you would load the SDK script instead, e.g., from a CDN of your choosing, such as [from jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/dropbox).